# How do I specify the configuration in a project constructor in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to solve a problem similar to the problem solved here: https://github.com/pniederw/elastic-deps/blob/master/build.gradle

Essentially, I have a map of gradle projects to prebuilt artifacts, stored in a file called PrebuiltArtifactMap.groovy (which I generate from my non-gradle build system) and I want to resolve a project dependency as an artifact dependency whenever the map has a suitable entry, otherwise leave it alone as a project dependency.

It works fine as long as I use the default configuration of the project I depend on, but when I want to use a specified configuration, I can't seem to make it work.

I am trying to write this:

```
def smartProject(String projectPath, String configuration=null) {
    return PrebuiltArtifactMap.resolveProjectDep(project, projectPath, configuration)
}

class PrebuiltArtifactMap
{
    static Map<String, String> projectToCoordinate = null;


    static Object resolveDep(String mapKey, String itemKey) {
        def map = projectToCoordinate[mapKey]
        if (map == null) {
            throw new GradleException("Prebuilt $mapKey doesn't exist.")
        }
        def artifact = map[itemKey]
        return artifact
    }

    static Object resolveProjectDep(Project dependentProject,
                                    String projectPath,
                                    String configuration=null) {
        // Attempt to locate gradle project in PrebuiltArtifactMap.groovy,
        // and resolve it into an artifact dependency if present.
        if (projectToCoordinate == null) {
            if (configuration == null) {
                return dependentProject.project(projectPath)
            } else {
                // *** THIS HERE doesn't work!!
                return dependentProject.project(path: projectPath,
                                                configuration: configuration)
            }
        } else {
            def artifact = resolveDep('ProjectMap', projectPath)
            if (artifact == null) {
                throw new GradleException("Prebuilt ProjectMap doesn't define an artifact for $projectPath.")
            }
            println "Resolving ${projectPath} to ${artifact}"
            if (artifact == 'LOCAL') {
                if (configuration == null) {
                    return dependentProject.project(projectPath)
                } else {
                    return dependentProject.project(path: projectPath, configuration: configuration)
                }
            }
            return artifact
        }
    }
}

({
   def mapFile = file("PrebuiltArtifactMap.groovy")
   if (mapFile.exists()) {
       PrebuiltArtifactMap.projectToCoordinate = evaluate(mapFile)
   }
})()
```

The part marked *** THIS HERE doesn't work!! fails, because the Project object does not have such a method.

What I want to do is replace declarations of the form

```
dependencies {
    myconfig project(":path:to:project", configuration: "archives")
}
```

with this:

```
dependencies {
    myconfig smartProject(":path:to:project", "archives")
}
```

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Note that I can work around the issue by forcing folks to use "runtime" as the configuration for the dependent project's artifacts section - which begs the question on how to maybe set the default config to be something else than "runtime"...

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the problem. Could you elaborate a bit more? Here's what I understand: You want to attach the method `resolveProjectDep` to the `Project` API? It would also be helpful if you could create a Gist or sample project on GitHub that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I added the complete code sample and hopefully clarified my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the method [project](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#project(java.util.Map)) on `DependencyHandler` which returns a `Dependency`. You can access the `DependencyHandler` from a `Project` instance through the method [getDependencies()](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getDependencies()).

In your case that would look like this:

```
dependentProject.dependencies.project(path: projectPath, configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Thanks... once you know, it's so easy :)